# Implementing equals method using compareTo

Tags: java, equals, compareto

General question: When implementing an override of the default `equals` method in Java, what concerns should I have about simply utilizing an already implemented `compareTo` method vs writing independent logic into the equals method? I noticed someone mention in another question that `foo.equals((String)null)` returns false whereas `String.compareTo((String)null)` throws a `NullPointerException`. What makes these inconsistent results ideal functionality?

Sample `equals` method:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (obj != null && obj instanceof MyClass) {
        MyClass msg = (MyClass)obj;
        return this.compareTo(msg) == 0;
    }
    return false;
}
```

**Edit:**
Quote from documentation on [Comparable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html)

> The natural ordering for a class C is said to be consistent with
>   equals if and only if e1.compareTo(e2) == 0 has the same boolean value
>   as e1.equals(e2) for every e1 and e2 of class C. Note that null is not
>   an instance of any class, and e.compareTo(null) should throw a
>   NullPointerException even though e.equals(null) returns false

**Edit:**

After further review, I find it of note that the [Comparable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) documentation also states the following:

> The implementor must ensure sgn(x.compareTo(y)) == -sgn(y.compareTo(x)) for all x and y. (This implies that x.compareTo(y) must throw an exception iff y.compareTo(x) throws an exception.)

Ergo, since `null.compareTo(x)` obviously throws a [NPE](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/NullPointerException.html), `x.compareTo(null)` should throw a NPE as well. Whereas for equals, that is not necessarily the case. I am pretty big on the proper handling of NPEs, so I find this relatively significant.

Comment: Note that while, ideally, `.compareTo()` should be consistent with `.equals()`, this is by no means a guaratee. See `BigDecimal` for instance. And yes, `null` handling if you go that route can be a problem.

Comment: `Double.NaN` has surprising behavior for both `equals(Object)` and `compareTo(Double)`.  `NaN.equals(NaN)` is `true`, but `NaN == NaN` is `false`. Similarly, `NaN` is the greatest `Double` in `compareTo` calls, and `NaN.compareTo(NaN) == 0`.  `equals` is consistent with `compareTo`, but the `Double` object does not follow IEEE standards in this case.  Necessary, but surprising.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The difference between `equals()` and `compareTo()` is that `equals()` just checks if two objects are equal to each other where the `compareTo()` is used to identify the natural order of the instances of specified class. Also `equals()` method has a contract with `hashCode()` method but `compareTo()` hasn't.

According to [JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html#compareTo%28T%29):

> Note that null is not an instance of any class, and e.compareTo(null)
>   should throw a NullPointerException even though e.equals(null) returns
>   false.
>
> It is strongly recommended, but not strictly required that
>   (x.compareTo(y)==0) == (x.equals(y)). Generally speaking, any class
>   that implements the Comparable interface and violates this condition
>   should clearly indicate this fact. The recommended language is "Note:
>   this class has a natural ordering that is inconsistent with equals."

You can feel free to reuse `compareTo()` method logic in your `equals()` method but keep in mind all the contracts to the `equals()`, `hashCode()` and contract from JavaDoc for `compareTo()` method. If they do not conflict with each other then go ahead.

I think that the enforcement of contracts is more important point.

Comment: "I think that the enforcement of contracts is more important point.
" <-- I can definetly agree with you there. Thanks for highlighting that these methods do indeed have distinguished intended functions.

Comment: While performance is always a valid concern, enforcing contracts looks to save me from writing more test cases in the long run. Thanks me for turning me onto that little nugget.

Answer (score 10):

`compareTo` *may* involve a lot more work than is necessary just to get an equality answer, which *may* end up being a performance issue, depending on your application usage.

Other than that, following [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) principles it would be a good idea to re-use the code as you have suggested.

Comment: Nice note about potential performance. For all my blustering about NPEs, I overlooked that my proposed code already handles them correctly assuming they are done properly in compareTo. The only remaining concern then is performance.