# How to get .equals() being symmetric when using .compareTo() in Java

Tags: java, sonarqube

There's a similar question here ([Implementing equals method using compareTo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16816827/implementing-equals-method-using-compareto)) - which in the end recommends to reuse `.compareTo()` to implement `.equals()` as long as the contracts aren't violated - my focus here is on the contract `x.equals(y) == y.equals(x)`. A simple implementation of `.equals()` would/could be

```
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
  return obj != null && (obj instanceof MyClass) && 0 == this.compareTo((MyClass)obj);
}
```

So here's my problem: When I have a `ParentClass` implementing it this way, and a `ChildClass` which `extends ParentClass`, I will have the problem that an instance of `ChildClass` is also an instance of `ParentClass`, but not vice versa.

So for an instance `parent` of `ParentClass` and an instance `child` of `ChildClass` it's at least possible - using the above `.equals()` - that `child.equals(parent) != parent.equals(child)`.

So how to implement `.equals()` using `.compareTo()` and guarantee `child.equals(parent) == parent.equals(child)`?

Any ideas? Thanks.

edit: the origin of this question is SonarQube which complains about the simple implementation not being symmetric - the above question is my interpretation of SonarQube's complaining. The solution should be symmetric but shouldn't involve too much changes.

Comment: as a sidenode, the check `obj != null` will also be done by `obj instanceof MyClass`, which makes the first one redundant.

Comment: Additional note, if you are concerned: The performance hit of `instanceof` is more or less [negligible](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/103564/the-performance-impact-of-using-instanceof-in-java). What actually matters a lot more is adding `(this == obj)`. And wrt. the actual question: That depends on your ordering. How do child classes order? Because if you have two different classes that have  `compareTo() == 0`, `compareTo()` violates equality (no matter for ordering, though). I usually tend to override `equals()` in subclasses, do the `instanceof` there and then delegate upwards.

Comment: It is most typically not logical or correct to write an equals method in which `child.equals(parent) == parent.equals(child)`.  If you adhere to the Liskov Substitution Principle, then it is generally not possible to write a subclass with new value components that does not break the `equals()` contract with its parent.  This is discussed in Effective Java, 2nd Ed. by J Bloch.

Comment: @scottb - `c.equals(p) == p.equals(c)` just means that both must be `true` or both must be `false` - so this is simply part of the equals contract - I don't see what should be wrong with this

Comment: @outofmind: if a child class adds new value components to the hierarchy, then by definition `c.equals(p)` can never be symmetric with `p.equals(c)` because an object of type parent has no knowledge of the child's new value components.  When equals is invoked on the parent object, it will never consider the child object c's new value components.  A workaround is to write `equals()` merthods that return true only if the two objects are of the same class, but this violates the Liskov Substitution Principle.

Comment: @scottb - so, what's your suggestion that satisfies the equals contracts as well as the LSP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, here's a solution that SonarQube (rule findbugs:EQ_UNUSUAL) is happy with ...

```
public boolean equals(Object obj)
{
    return obj != null && this.getClass().equals(obj.getClass()) && this.compareTo(obj) == 0;
}
```

At least this seems to be compact and should satisfy the contracts.

Answer (score 1):

Equality checking using `instanceof` only is fundamentally unsafe. If equality with subclasses doesn't make sense you need to compare the equality of the classes using `this.getClass().equals(other.getClass())`. If you want to allow child classes to be equal to parents (this is in many cases invalid) you have to check the relationship and delegate to the child. It is impossible for the parent to know the correct definition of equality.

```
class Parent {
  boolean equals(Object other) {
    if (! other instanceof Parent) return false
    if (! other.getClass().equals(Parent.class)) return other.equals(this);
    // Otherwise compare two objects that precisely have the type Parent
  }
}
```

Note that if the child is not final, you will also have to do that (appropriately) with the child. In the child equals, you can allow that the other is an instance  of `Parent` (but you do need to compare equality appropriately).

Comment: Whether or not you should use compareTo depends on the implementation. In any case it is safer to do it on the child class (although it may be valid to do so on the parent as well - depending on the semantics). In general, I would still use the parent.equals method, as the child can then determine whether equality is valid independently from compareTo (note that the parent does not know about the child, but the child must know of the parent)

Comment: Thanks for directing me to `.getClass()` - this led me to a solution that fits my needs - thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to override the equals method in child class to check the obj for parent class?

Answer (score 0):

> So how to implement `.equals()` using `.compareTo()` and guarantee `child.equals(parent) == parent.equals(child)`?

It seems not correct to check equality of two distinct object. You can create an interface that, implement to `parent` then check equality of child and parent with this interface.

Comment: Origin of the question is SonarQube which complains about this implementation being not symmetric - so I'm trying to find a solution which doesn't involve too much changes to the simple solution